# Android studio different fragments unwillingly sharing same R.id.(linearlayout)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm creating fragment, on this fragment i create another fragment. It should be seen [ 1) ] but is instead showing as [ 2) ]

[image: s]

```
start.java (it's a fragment inside navigation for bottom slider)
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            contadorEgresos++;
            EgresosDiarios fragEgresosDiarios = new EgresosDiarios();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("index",i);
            fragEgresosDiarios.setArguments(b);
            ft.add(R.id.llEgresos, fragEgresosDiarios, "tagEgresos" + contadorEgresos);
            ft.commit();

            fragEgresosDiarios.agregarTarjeta();
```

### }´

```
EgresosDiarios.java
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View ll =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_egresos_diarios, container, false);

        llFragmentTarjetaEgresos = ll.findViewById(R.id.llFragmentTarjetaEgresos);
        fabAgregarEgreso = ll.findViewById(R.id.fabAgregarEgreso);
        tvFecha = ll.findViewById(R.id.tvFecha);

        int index = getArguments().getInt("index");

        if(index == 0){
            tvFecha.setText("Hoy");
        }else{
            tvFecha.setText("Ayer");
        }

        //agregarTarjeta();

        fabAgregarEgreso.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                TarjetaEgresos fragment = (TarjetaEgresos) fm.findFragmentByTag("tagTarjetaEgresos"+1);
                for(int i = 1; i <= contadorTarjetaEgresos; i++){
                    fragment = (TarjetaEgresos) fm.findFragmentByTag("tagTarjetaEgresos"+i);
                    if (fragment.isModificando()){
                        Modificando = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!Modificando){

                    agregarTarjeta();

                }else{
                    if(mListenerDebeTerminarModificacion != null){
                        mListenerDebeTerminarModificacion.debeTerminarModificacion(true);
                    }
                }
                Modificando = false;
            }
        });
        return ll;
    }

    public void agregarTarjeta(){

        contadorTarjetaEgresos++;
        TarjetaEgresos fragTarjetaEgresos = new TarjetaEgresos();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add( R.id.llFragmentTarjetaEgresos, fragTarjetaEgresos, "tagTarjetaEgresos" + contadorTarjetaEgresos);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Inside `agregarTarjeta()`, the line `ft.add(R.id.llFragmentTarjetaEgresos, ...)` calls for a vertical linear layout inside each fragment, but instead is only calling for the linear layout inside only the first fragment.

Comment: You need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` – not `getFragmentManager()` – to handle the `Fragment`s nested in other `Fragment`s.

Comment: You are my new god. If you answer it in the section i'll select yours as correct answer. Thank you very much

Comment: Oh, it's cool. :-) This is a somewhat common issue, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate of another similar question where I provided the same answer. Thank you, though. I really appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!